# JSON object format

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, json

This may be a stupid question but I want to ask because it may be an indication of a mistake I may be making.

I just created my first Web API project and started hosting it as a website. Initially, I was getting XML responses, so I added the following line in the Register method:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
```

I now get JSON results but my JSON results are not nicely formatted. They all come back as a regular string.

I get this:

```
{ "id": 123, "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Smith",
"gender": "male"}
```

I've seen a lot of examples where the result looks like this:

```
{
   "id": 123,
   "firstName": "John",
   "lastName": "Smith",
   "gender": "male"
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

-- Edit ---

Thank you all for your response.

I wonder if the way I'm returning the data is causing this formatting issue. I'm just returning my POCO class and lettting the Web API handle any serialization. Is this the right way to return my data?

```
public IHttpActionResult GetSpecifiedPerson(int id)
        {
            Person user = new Person();
            user.PersonId = 1234567;
            user.FirstName = "Jane";
            user.LastName = "Doe";

            return Ok(user);
        }
```

Comment: Is just formatting and nothing else. Your json seems to be fine.

Comment: off topic nothing programming part, why you want to well formatted? paste here your json code http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Just formatting. The json object I get seems to be fine. I was wondering why my object was not nicely formatted.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your JSON. When you parse that you won't face any problems.

Comment: Is the way I'm returning the data causing the formatting issue?

Comment: Yes most probably it is your JsonFormatter. See there are different JSON formaters and parsers and some of them add extra spaces so the JSON data looks good and some of them don't like in your case. But that doesn't make a difference as long as you are able to PUT and EXTRACT values from that JSON object. Like you can eat steamed rice or boiled rice, doesn't matter cause you can eat both and nothing will happen to you ;)

Answer (score 0):

your JSON result is completely fine. nothing wrong.
most examples are formatted nicely for readability. nothing else